出力結果にattack()の項目を加えたい
Rep1405.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream> //ファイル入出力用(←new)
#include "PC.h"

void show_PCL(std::vector<Actor*>& acts)
{   // Actor* の vector である acts の情報一覧標示
    std::vector<Actor*>::iterator p;
    for (p = acts.begin(); p != acts.end(); p++) {
        std::cout << (*p)->to_string() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "PC:Player Charactor クラスの動作確認\n";

    // ブルーチーム
    std::vector<Actor*> blue;
    blue.push_back(new PC("田中"));
    blue.push_back(new PC("佐藤"));
    blue.push_back(new PC("金子"));

    std::cout << "ブルーチーム\n";
    show_PCL(blue);

    // レッドチーム
    std::vector<Actor*> red;
    red.push_back(new PC("松本"));
    red.push_back(new PC("西田"));
    red.push_back(new PC("マイケル"));

    std::cout << "レッドチーム\n";
    show_PCL(red);

    // 自動戦闘のターン数を確認 (↓ new ここから)
    std::cout << "自動戦闘は何回実行しますか？ > ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;  // ループ回数を指定

    // ログファイル出力準備
    std::ofstream log("AutoActionLog.txt");
    if (!log) {
        std::cout << "AutoActionLog.txt が開けませんでした。\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }  // ログファイル準備
    // ↑ new ここまで


  // 戦闘開始
    std::cout << "\n--- 戦闘開始 ---\n";
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { // ← 5回ではなく n 回 (← new)
        // ブルーチームの行動 + レッドチームの行動 = 1セット

        // ブルーチームのターン
        std::vector<Actor*>::iterator p;
        for (p = blue.begin(); p != blue.end(); p++) {
            (*p)->auto_action(blue, red);
            // ↑ blue が味方, red が敵
        }

        // レッドチームのターン
        for (p = red.begin(); p != red.end(); p++) {
            (*p)->auto_action(red, blue);
            // ↑ red が味方, blue が敵
        }

        // 1回分の戦闘ログをファイル出力 (new)
        log << "loop : " << i << std::endl;
        for (p = blue.begin(); p != blue.end(); p++) {
            log << (*p)->to_string() << std::endl;
        }
        for (p = red.begin(); p != red.end(); p++) {
            log << (*p)->to_string() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    log.close(); // ログファイルを閉じる (new)


    // 戦闘終了
    std::cout << "\n--- 戦闘終了 ---\n";

    // 結果発表
    std::cout << "\n--- 結果発表 ---\n";
    std::cout << "ブルーチーム\n";
    show_PCL(blue); // blue の情報一覧
    std::cout << "レッドチーム\n";
    show_PCL(red);  // red の情報一覧
}

PC.cpp
#include <sstream>  // ← to_string() で使用
#include "PC.h"

int PC::updateHP(int n)
{
    HP += n;                    // HPをnの値で増減させる．
    if (HP < 0) HP = 0;         // ※ HPは0より小さい値にはしない．
    if (HP > MaxHP) HP = MaxHP; // ※ HPはMaxHPを超える値にはしない．

    return HP;
}

int PC::updateMP(int n)
{
    MP += n;                    // MPをnの値で増減させる．
    if (MP < 0) MP = 0;         // ※ MPは0より小さい値にはしない．
    if (MP > MaxMP) MP = MaxMP; // ※ MPはMaxMPを超える値にはしない．

    return MP;
}

void PC::attack(Actor* act)
{   // 指定したオブジェクトのHPにダメージを与える．
    // ※ 0～10の乱数でactのHPを減らす．
    int d = Actor::dice(10);
    act->updateHP(-d);          // 自分ではなくactのHPにダメージ
}

void PC::heal(Actor* act)
{   // MPを消費して，指定したオブジェクトのHPを回復する．
    // ※ MP消費は5，回復量は0～30の乱数
    if (this->MP >= 5) {        // 自分のMP残量5以上で実行
        this->MP -= 5;      // 自分のMP消費
        int d = Actor::dice(30);
        act->updateHP(d);   // 自分ではなくactのHP回復
    }
}

void PC::auto_attack(std::vector<Actor*>& acts)
{   // acts 中の Actor に攻撃する．
    // ※ 乱数で acts 中のどれかを指定して攻撃．
    int x = Actor::dice(acts.size() - 1);   // 0 ～（Actorsの数 - 1）の乱数生成
    attack(acts[x]);
    // ↑ acts は Actor のポインタの vector であることに注意!!
}

void PC::attack_weak(std::vector<Actor*>& acts)
{   // acts 中の最小 HP の Actor 攻撃する．
    Actor* target = Actor::get_MinHP_Actor(acts);   // 最小 HP の Actor を見つける．
    attack(target);     // 最小 HP の Actor を攻撃する．
}

void PC::auto_heal(std::vector<Actor*>& acts)
{   // acts 中の Actor を回復する．
    // ※ 乱数で acts 中のどれかを指定して回復．
    int x = Actor::dice(acts.size() - 1);   // 0 ～（Actorの数 - 1）の乱数生成
    heal(acts[x]);
    // ↑ acts は Actor のポインタの vector であることに注意!!
}

void PC::heal_weak(std::vector<Actor*>& acts)
{   // acts 中の最小 HP の Actor を回復する．
    Actor* target = Actor::get_MinHP_Actor(acts);   // 最小 HP の Actor を見つける．
    heal(target);       // 最小 HP の Actor を回復する．
}


// 問題文で指定された割合に変更する。
void PC::auto_action(std::vector<Actor*>& friends, std::vector<Actor*>& enemies)
{
    // 敵 (enemies) と味方 (friends) の情報を利用して、何かの行動を起こす。
    // ※ 乱数で発生する行動の割合変更 (変更)
    // ※ auto_attack() : attack_weak() : auto_heal() : heal_weak() = 3:4:1:2
    int x = Actor::dice(9); // ※ 以下のifの条件調整 (new)
    if (x < 3) { // x が 0～2 で auto_attack()
        auto_attack(enemies); // ← enemies 中のどれかを乱数で選んで攻撃
    }
    else if (x < 7) { // x が 3～6 で attack_weak()
        attack_weak(enemies); // ← enemies 中の最小 HP の敵を選んで攻撃
    }
    else if (x == 7) { // x が 7 で autoheal()
        auto_heal(friends); // ← friends 中のどれかを乱数で選んで回復
    }
    else { // それ以外 (x が 8, 9) で heal_weak()
        heal_weak(friends); // ← friends 中の最小 HP の味方を回復
    }
}


std::string PC::to_string()
{   // オブジェクト情報を文字列にして返す．
    // ID, Name, HP, MaxHP, MP, MaxMP をスペースで区切って連結した文字列を返す．
    // ※ Actor クラスでの private と protected の扱いに注意．
    // ↑ private は，派生クラスであっても直接アクセスできないので，
    //   アクセッサ（値を参照したり変更したりするメソッド）を利用する．
    // ↑ protected は，派生クラスから直接アクセスできる．

    std::ostringstream oss; // 出力用ストリームを準備
    // 出力用ストリーム oss に出力（画面に出力するのではない）
    oss << getID() << " " << getName() << " "   // ID と Name は Actor の private
        << HP << " " << MaxHP << " "        // HP, MaxHP, MP, MaxMP は protected
        << MP << " " << MaxMP << " " << std::flush;
    // std::flush は，出力用バッファの内容をすべて送信する．
    // std::endl は，上記に加えてかいｇ用する．

    return oss.str();   // oss に出力された内容を文字列として取り出して返す．
}

PC.h
#pragma once
#include "Actor.h"

class PC :
    public Actor
{
public:
    PC(std::string name) :Actor(name) {};   // コンストラクタ
    // ↑基本クラスである Actor のコンストラクタを流用

    // 以下のメソッドはすべて Actor クラスの純粋仮想関数を実装するための宣言
    int updateHP(int n);        // HPを増減させる値を与えて，その結果のHPを返す．
    int updateMP(int n);        // MPを増減させる値を与えて，その結果のMPを返す．
    void attack(Actor* act);    // 指定したオブジェクトのHPにダメージを与える．
    void heal(Actor* act);      // MPを消費して，指定したオブジェクトのHPを回復する．
    void auto_attack(std::vector<Actor*>& acts);    // acts 中の Actor 1体に攻撃する.
    void attack_weak(std::vector<Actor*>& acts);    // acts 中の HP が最小の個体を攻撃する．
    void auto_heal(std::vector<Actor*>& acts);      // acts 中の Actor 1体を回復する.
    void heal_weak(std::vector<Actor*>& acts);      // acts 中の HP が最低の個体を回復する．
    void auto_action(std::vector<Actor*>& friends, std::vector<Actor*>& enemies);
    // ↑敵(enemies)と味方(friends)の情報を利用して何かの行動を起こす.
    std::string to_string();    // オブジェクト情報を文字列にして返す.
};

Actor.cpp
#include <random>
#include "Actor.h"

int Actor::CN = 0;  // キャラクター総数

Actor::Actor(std::string name)  // コンストラクタ
{
    ID = ++Actor::CN;   // キャラクタ総数を更新して，その値を ID とする．
    Name = name;        // name で指定された文字列を Name とする．
    HP = MaxHP = 50;    // HP, MaxHP を初期化する．（50）
    MP = MaxMP = 20;    // MP, MaxMP を初期化する．（20）
}

int Actor::dice(int n)
{   // 単純に　rand() を利用しても良いが，以下のような方法の方がより乱数に近い．
    // レポート提出時は，単純に rand() を利用したものでも良い．
    std::random_device md;  // 非決定的な乱数生成器を作成する準備
    std::mt19937 mt(md());  // メルセンヌ・ツイスタによる乱数生成の設定
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> randN(0, n);    // 0～n の乱数生成

    return randN(mt);   // 0～n の整数乱数を生成して返す．    
}

Actor* Actor::get_MinHP_Actor(std::vector<Actor*>& acts)
{   // acts 中で最小HPの Actor をみつけて，そのポインタを返す．
    int minHP = MaxHP;  // HP の最小値を保存する．初期値は MaxHP.
    int x = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < acts.size(); i++) {
        if (minHP > acts[i]->HP) {
            minHP = acts[i]->HP;
            x = i;
        }
    }

    return acts[x]; // 最小 HP の Actor のポインタを返す．
}

Actor.h
#pragma once
#include <string>   // 文字列処理用
#include <vector>   // vector の利用

class Actor     // vector コンテナを利用するクラス
{
private:
    static int CN;      // キャラクター総数（クラス変数）
    int ID;             // キャラクターID
    std::string Name;   // キャラクター名
protected:
    int HP, MaxHP, MP, MaxMP;
public:
    Actor(std::string name);    // コンストラクタ（オブジェクト名を指定）
protected:
    int dice(int n);            // 0～n のint型乱数を返す．
public:
    int getID() { return ID; }              // ID のゲッタ
    std::string getName() { return Name; }  // Name のゲッタ
    Actor* get_MinHP_Actor(std::vector <Actor*>& acts); // acts 中の HP が最小の Actor を返す．

    // 以下のメソッドはすべて純粋仮想関数
    virtual int updateHP(int n) = 0;        // HPを増減させる値を与え，その結果のHPを返す．
    virtual int updateMP(int n) = 0;        // MPを増減させる値を与え，その結果のMPを返す．
    virtual void attack(Actor* act) = 0;    // 指定したオブジェクトの HP にダメージを与える．
    virtual void heal(Actor* act) = 0;  // MPを消費して，指定したオブジェクトの HP を回復する．
    virtual void auto_attack(std::vector<Actor*>& acts) = 0;    // acts 中の Actor 1体に攻撃する．
    virtual void attack_weak(std::vector<Actor*>& acts) = 0;    // acts 中の HP が最低の個体を攻撃．
    virtual void auto_heal(std::vector<Actor*>& acts) = 0;      // acts 中の Actor 1体を回復する．
    virtual void heal_weak(std::vector<Actor*>& acts) = 0;      // acts 中の HP が最低の個体を回復．
    virtual void auto_action(std::vector<Actor*>& friends, std::vector<Actor*>& enemies) = 0;
    // ↑敵（enemies）と味方（friends）の情報を利用して，何かの行動を起こす．
    virtual std::string to_string() = 0;    // オブジェクト情報を文字列として返す．
};

現在
PC:Player Charactor クラスの動作確認
ブルーチーム
1 田中 50 50 20 20
2 佐藤 50 50 20 20
3 金子 50 50 20 20
レッドチーム
4 松本 50 50 20 20
5 西田 50 50 20 20
6 マイケル 50 50 20 20
自動戦闘は何回実行しますか？ > 5

--- 戦闘開始 ---

--- 戦闘終了 ---

--- 結果発表 ---
ブルーチーム
1 田中 49 50 15 20
2 佐藤 37 50 10 20
3 金子 46 50 10 20
レッドチーム
4 松本 50 50 10 20
5 西田 45 50 15 20
6 マイケル 30 50 10 20

のように出力される。
これを、
[loop：1]
attack(2)：スミス⇒ウルフ1
heal(2)：メアリー⇒スミス
attack(8)：ジャック⇒ウルフ1
heal(25)：ゴブ1⇒ゴブ1
heal(5)：ゴブ2⇒ゴブ2
heal(24)：ウルフ1⇒ウルフ1
--ステータス--
スミス　50 50 20 20
メアリー　50 50 15 20
ジャック　50 50 20 20
ゴブ1　50 50 15 20
ゴブ2　50 50 15 20
ウルフ1　50 50 15 20

[loop：2]
attack(4)：スミス⇒ウルフ1
attack(3)：メアリー⇒ウルフ1
attack(6)：ジャック⇒ウルフ1
attack(8)：ゴブ1⇒ジャック
attack(5)：ゴブ2⇒ジャック
attack(5)：ウルフ1⇒スミス
--ステータス--
スミス　50 50 20 20
メアリー　50 50 15 20
ジャック　50 50 20 20
ゴブ1　50 50 15 20
ゴブ2　50 50 15 20
ウルフ1　41 50 15 20

（名前は違うが気にしないでください）
このような形式で出力したい
入力

それぞれの行動についてログを出すのに必要な情報は、それぞれの行動を実際に処理する関数の中ですべて揃っていそうなので、単に順番にログを出すだけなら行動を処理する関数（PC::attack と PC::heal）の中で出力すれば良さそうです。
ただしメインループの中以外で出力することになるので設計として出力処理の場所が散らばるのが気になる可能性はあります。もしそういった趣旨の質問なのであれば、PC::auto_action が選択された行動結果を返すようにしてメインループの中で出力するようにするなど、実装の変更をする流れになりそうです。
もしこれが回答になっていなければ、以下のヘルプページを参考にしつつ質問文を編集して、やりたいことをやるにあたってどの部分にお困りなのかを説明するようにしてみてください。

再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方
良い質問をするには？

